# Google Public API Key doesn’t work

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I'm trying to access public activities from Google+ using the Google API. So I created a new project in the Developers Console, activated the Google+ API and created a key for browser applications (Public API access).

If I’am trying to search public posts using the following link there comes up an error "accessNotConfigured" (`{key}` stands for my real key):

`https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities?query=%23love&key={key}`

I have double checked all (even tried to access the Maps V3 API with my key for testing if it works on another API).

Have I done something wrong?

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: I have just added a new key once more. Now it says "Any referrer allowed" (which it not done before) and suddenly all works fine. This issue is now solved for me. Is there a way to delete this Question?

Comment: There is, but don't. Leave the question here so someone else may find it and find your solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have just added a new key once more. Now it says "Any referrer allowed" (which it not done before) and suddenly all works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a step-by-step that I hope will be helpful:

1. Go to google developers console -> your app -> APIS & AUTH -> Credentials
2. Click on 'Create New Key' under Public API access
   [image: Step 2]
3. Choose 'Browser Key'
   [image: Step 3]
4. Enjoy public api access with your key (be sure to leave referers blank!)
   [image: Step 3]